# How can I allow my HTTP request to continue propagating through my app after a caught failure?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, scope, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 which sits on top of Angular 2.

I am using a service in my app to handle all API requests.  Some of those requests carry an Authorization header.  My API can return a 401 if the auth fails, and I am currently handling that by showing an error to the user and navigating them to the login screen.  That all works great and I publish an event for these errors which I subscribe to elsewhere to handle the logic (as I can't use navigation controllers in a service).

Code for `api.js` service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Api {
  base_url: string = 'https://***.com';
  url: string = this.base_url + '/api/v1';
  authurl: string = this.base_url + '/oauth/token';
  grant_type: string = 'password';
  client_id: string = '1';
  client_secret: string = '***';
  access_token: string;

  constructor(
    public http: Http, 
    private storage: Storage,
    public events: Events) {

    // Grab access token and store it
    storage.get('access_token').then((val) => {
      this.access_token = val;
    });
  }

  // Performs a GET request with auth headers
  get(endpoint: string, params?: any) {
    if(!params) {
      params = [];
    }
    params['grant_type'] = this.grant_type;
    params['client_id'] = this.client_id;
    params['client_secret'] = this.client_secret;

    let headers: Headers = this.getHeaders();

    return this.getApiToken().flatMap(data => {

      headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + data);

      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      // Support easy query params for GET requests
      if (params) {
        let p = new URLSearchParams();
        for (let k in params) {
          p.set(k, params[k]);
        }
        // Set the search field if we have params and don't already have
        // a search field set in options.
        options.search = !options.search && p || options.search;
      } 

      return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + endpoint, options)
        .catch((error: any) => {
          if (error.status === 500) {
            this.events.publish('api:generalError', error);
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
          else if (error.status === 401) {
            this.events.publish('api:unauthorized', error);
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
        });
    }).share();
  }
}
```

The problem is down to the 'Loading...' dialog that I show to the user while the `get` request is taking place.  Before the method is called I create a loading dialog and dismiss it on success or failure.  The problem is that I don't have any scope of this inside `api.js` in order to dismiss it when a 401 or 500 is caught.

Here's a sample of my logic around this:

```
let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: "Please wait..."
});
loader.present();

this.trainingProgramme.get_programmes()
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe((res) => {

  this.currentItems = res.training_programmes;

}, (err) => {
  // Error
  console.log(err);
}, () => {
  loader.dismiss();
});
```

I don't think it's important, but I also have a service for each entity which in turn calls `api.js` service.  In the above example it's `this.trainingProgramme`, which looks like this:

```
  get_programmes() {
    let seq = this.api.get('training-programmes');

    seq
      .subscribe();

    return seq;
  }
```

I thought the way I approached this was all correct, however I can't see a way I can handle the 'Loading' issue.

Is there a way I can have the `get` method continue within my app even after an error has been caught, so that my `loader.dismiss()` code is ran within the correct scope?

I really don't want to have to use the loader inside the service (not sure I'm even able to?) as this seems like bad design, and I don't want to always show a loader, so it belongs in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `.finally` operator, which will execute always even if there's an error on the Observable.

The `complete` callback (the last from the `.subscribe` call) will not trigger if an `error` happens.

Remember to include it:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';

...

this.trainingProgramme.get_programmes()
 .finally(() => loader.dismiss())
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe((res) => {
   ...
 }
 , (err) => {
  // Error
  console.log(err);
 });
```

By the way, consider updating your code from `@angular/http` to the new [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working.  I added a console.log() into the `finally(() => console.log('testing')` but nothing happens - no output, the just same as before with a 401 occuring and the login screen appearing with the Loading... dialog overlaid :(

Comment: Using the finally() method should work here. You are subscribing to the observable once in the get_programmes() function without handling any errors. Perhaps this subsciber trigger the error and error handler before you handle the error? Could you remove that line and see if there is any difference?

Comment: That's sorted it.  The extra intermediate `subscribe()` must have been triggering it early.  Thanks.